# Incorrect integer value: '%s' for column `materialdatabase`.`tensilesummary`.`batchnumber` at row 1

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, mariadb

```
batchnumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
def update_batchnum():
    try:
        for num in range(len(batchnumbers)):
            query = ("INSERT INTO tensilesummary(batchnumber) VALUES ('%s');")
            cursor.execute(query,batchnumbers[num])
            mariadb_connection.commit() 
            print("Batchnumber successfullt inserted into tensilesummary table")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error: 
        print("Failed using updatebatchnum to insert into tensilesummary table:{}".format(error))

update_batchnum()
```

Returned error: Failed using updatebatchnum to insert into tensilesummary table:1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: '%s' for column `materialdatabase`.`tensilesummary`.`batchnumber` at row 1.

I tried to change sql_mode = "" in my.ini but it doesn't work.

Comment: That probably means that your id is an AUTO_INCREMENT integer and you're trying to send a string. You should specify a column list and omit it from your INSERT.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to sql, I'm not quite sure what you mean? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You don't show the code creating your cursor. If you want to use parameterized queries (using the `'%s'` in `values`) you'll need to create it like this: `cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When using placeholders, don't put them in quotes, it's also waste of space to append a semicolon.

`query = "INSERT INTO tensilesummary (batchnumber) VALUES (%s)"`

2. According to DBAPI 2.0 (PEP-249) the second parameter of cursor.execute must be a tuple, so it should be `(batchnumbers[num],)`